# Finding probability of individual trials from n successes

Tags: probability

I'm a bit confused here. I ran a simulation and was able to decide that in my particular model, i almost always get a 55% success rate for large simulations. So is the probability of success 0.55?

If not, how do i find out what the probability of an individual success is?

Comment: What are you modeling?  Was there an a priori reason to expect a different answer?

Comment: What do you mean for a large simulation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you cannot find the exact value of the probability using a simulation (an empirical method has never proven any mathematical truth). But still, by the law of large numbers, it is "quite likely" (whatever this means) that the probability is around 0.55.
In fact, either you have a theoretical situation in which you define what the probabilistic model is, and then you can compute the exact probabilities; or, if you are facing a real-life event, you just do what you did and assume that the result is right if you have let your simulation run long enough.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be that you **almost always** get 55% success rate for large simulations. Instead, you should get **around** 55% success rate, plus or minus a few percent, for it to be consistent with the true probability being **approximately** 55%. You can compute the [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) to determine how **confident** you can be of your **estimate** of the true probability. But always remember that you can never get the true probability (assuming the data you have really comes from identical independent Bernoulli random variables), and you can never even be 100% certain that it is not actually say 1% (and you were just 'lucky' in all your tests), though your certainty increases with the sample size.

This empirical observation that real world processes that seem random often do obey the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) is what makes the mathematical theory of probability relevant and useful for the practical analysis of such real world processes, because the law of large numbers can be proven in probability theory, and it concurs with what is observed (up to confidence intervals of course).

Comment: And if you find that your large simulations are always getting very close to 55% and not deviating from it as would be indicated by the central limit theorem, it is evidence that your samples are not independent. CLT applies here because the sum of Bernoulli random variables is a Binomial random variable and when normalized it converges quickly to the standard Normal distribution.